# Did British prime minister Rishi Sunak unsuccessfully sit the exam for a Winchester College scholarship?

Tags: united-kingdom

The Tatler has [reported](https://www.tatler.com/article/rishi-sunak-chancellor-of-the-exchequer-feature) regarding British prime minister Rishi Sunak that "*[no] sooner was he accepted [into Winchester College] [...,] [his] good fortune [...] foundered: he missed out on the expected scholarship.*"

This suggests that he entered the school into the non-scholarship part, and then when already a pupil he sat [the examination for a scholarship](https://www.winchestercollege.org/admissions/election) and failed it. (Taking it when already a non-scholar pupil is allowed, assuming the pupil is still young enough.)

Has this been publicly established? The only reports I have seen are derivative of the report in the Tatler, for example in the [Metro](https://metro.co.uk/2022/10/24/where-did-prime-minister-rishi-sunak-go-to-school-17624942/) and in the [Express](https://www.express.co.uk/news/politics/1687540/rishi-sunak-school-prime-minister-winchester-college-spt).

Or did Mr Sunak sit the Election examination in the hope of a scholarship, fail to achieve high enough marks, but receive an offer of an ordinary place at the school instead?

The phrase "missed out" is somewhat vague. What I would like to know is whether he sat the scholarship exam and failed it, meaning that he failed to qualify for a scholarship; and if so, was this before he entered the school or when he was already at it. (There is even a slight possibility that it could have been both, if he sat the exam twice.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, he sat the scholarship exam for Winchester in 1993 but was unsuccessful in being granted a place as a Scholar. However, he did do well enough in the exams to be offered a non-scholarship place, and appears to have been granted some form of financial support, if not a full scholarship. See Lord Ashcroft's book *Going for Broke - the Rise of Rishi Sunak*:

> The couple now had three children at private day schools, a huge drain
> on the family finances. Boarding at Winchester, which cost
> substantially more than a private day school, would be a significant
> additional burden. Without the benefit of inherited wealth, it was a
> stretch, so they encouraged Sunak to try for a scholarship.
>
> At Winchester, these highly competitive awards were not automatically
> accompanied by a reduction in fees and were more sought after for the
> academic prestige they conferred. Nonetheless, a scholarship would
> make a bursary easier to obtain, and so they thought it was worth a
> try. In a manner that would become a feature of the way he approached
> challenges in later life, Sunak did everything possible to prepare for
> what he knew would be an incredibly rigorous set of exams. The
> scholarship tests – known at Winchester as ‘Election’ – took place
> over several days.

He goes on:

> In the event, he had not quite made the grade to enter Winchester as a
> scholar. His parents had always been realistic about his chances:
> Stroud did not reckon to send many pupils to the major public schools
> and getting a scholarship to Winchester – one of the most selective
> schools in the country – was a big ask of any boy. Tim Johnson, an Old
> Wykehamist who is a year older than the Chancellor, also sat the
> scholarship exams and says they were tougher than any other academic
> test he would take in later life. ‘I failed them as well. They were
> the hardest exams I’ve ever taken, up to and including my finals. I
> remember the French oral being done in Senegalese, so not only was it
> in French, it was also in West African French.’ **Nonetheless, Sunak had
> done well enough in the tests to be offered a regular place. It seems
> his parents may also have been offered some financial help by the
> school: he has since said somewhat vaguely that he was ‘helped along
> the way with support and scholarships here and there’.**
>
> At the time, his achievement in getting in to such an elite
> establishment was quite a talking point among teachers and fellow
> pupils at Stroud. ‘Not many kids get into Winchester, which is why I
> remember that he did. It is quite a rarity,’ recalls Olly Case.

Ashcroft cites Sunak's 2019 interview with Nick Robinson on his *Political Thinking* podcast as his reference for that final bolded quotation.

Comment: Many thanks for this prompt and informative answer. So he sat the Election exam for a scholarship, failed to get a scholarship, but was offered and accepted a non-scholarship place. Presumably that was in 1993 and this was the only time he sat the Election exam. (He would have been too old in 1994.) Note that the concept of "full scholarship" does not apply to Winchester. A scholarship there is a place in the most selective part of the school, where boys are not "Commoners" who live in one of several "Houses" but rather "Collegemen" who live in a special part of the school called "College".

Comment: So a pupil is either a Scholar or a Commoner, regardless of whether or not he receives any bursaries. There are two separate exams: Election (for a scholarship) and Entrance (for a non-scholarship place), but those who fail in Election can still be offered a non-scholarship place, which must have been what happened with Mr Sunak. Thanks again.

Comment: @tell I see, I shall make this clear. This was definitely in 1993 - the chapter concludes "The year was 1993 and Sunak had just turned thirteen. For the Conservative government of the time, these were dark days indeed."